# Telegram API swift (or objective-c) client, to read channel messages

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, telegram

I'm wondering if it's possible the read messages from telegram channel from the iOS app.

I want to parse public channel to implement an application which will show a map with latest Air-Raid sirens in Ukraine. There's official channel here - https://t.me/air_alert_ua, which I'd like to parse, and then draw an overlay on the map in an iOS app, like on the following [web-site](https://war.ukrzen.in.ua/alerts/).

I know that there's [telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) client for python, but running python inside iOS app isn't a very good idea and perhaps there's a better way. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Telegram has tdlib (https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/getting-started), and someone did create this library based on it: https://github.com/Swiftgram/TDLibKit

Comment: BUT: collecting data directly on device is slow, resource intensive, unreliable, and has to be developed for each platform separately. So apps like the one you like are almost never doing a direct integration on device. Typically they have a backend (e.g. hosted on AWS, or Azure, or any other cloud service), that is constantly collecting data by polling the third-party service (Telegram in this case), parsing and converting data into format that is convenient for clients. And client's job will be then just to render a map based on that info.

Comment: Слава Україні! I guess best idea is connect with creators of this chanel and mobile apps and provide your ideas. I found this post on DOU https://dou.ua/forums/topic/36811/ and you can contact author